# Pass an array of pointers in WebAssembly

Tags: c++, webassembly

I'm using the wasm native API.
I allocate memory for 2 arrays. I set values there.
Next, I allocate memory for an array of pointers to these arrays.
And I also set values. Next, I pass an array of pointers to the calc function.
It works. But is it correct to do so? Is it correct to allocate 4 bytes per pointer (Int32Array)?
Can the moduleExports.malloc function return a pointer with a number greater than 4 bytes?
I understand the allowable memory area for 4 bytes of 4gb of memory? 2^32/1024/1024/1024 = 4gb

file: index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="initializeWasm()">
        <script src="demo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

file demo.js

```
const initializeWasm = () => {
  const importObject = {
    env: {
    },
    wasi_snapshot_preview1: {
      proc_exit: () => {},
    },
  }

  WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('./example.wasm'), importObject).then((result) => {
    const moduleExports = result.instance.exports
    const moduleMemory = moduleExports.memory
    const float64Array = new Float64Array(moduleMemory.buffer)
    const int32Array = new Int32Array(moduleMemory.buffer)

    const data1 = [1, 2]
    const data2 = [5, 6, 7]

    const byteEl = Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT

    const pointer1 = moduleExports.malloc(byteEl * data1.length)
    const pointer2 = moduleExports.malloc(byteEl * data2.length)

    const index1 = pointer1 / byteEl
    const index2 = pointer2 / byteEl

    float64Array.set(data1, index1)
    float64Array.set(data2, index2)

    const pointers = [pointer1, pointer2]
    const byteElPointers = Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT // Right ??????
    const byteElSizes = Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
    const pointerArray = moduleExports.malloc(byteElPointers * pointers.length)
    const pointerSize = moduleExports.malloc(byteElSizes * pointers.length)

    int32Array.set(pointers, pointerArray / byteElPointers)
    int32Array.set([data1.length, data2.length], pointerSize / byteElSizes)
    
    moduleExports.calc(pointerArray, pointerSize, pointers.length)

    console.log(data1.map((n, i) => float64Array[index1 + i]))
    console.log(data2.map((n, i) => float64Array[index2 + i]))

    moduleExports.free(pointerArray)
    moduleExports.free(pointerSize)
    moduleExports.free(pointer1)
    moduleExports.free(pointer2)
  })
}
```

file main.cpp

```
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

extern "C" {
    #ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
        EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    #endif
    void calc(double** data, int* sizes, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            double* arr = data[i];
            int size = sizes[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
                ++arr[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

build command

```
emcc main.cpp -o ./../web/example.wasm -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_malloc','_free']
```

Comment: *Is it correct to allocate 4 bytes per pointer* -- Is this for 64-bit programs?  If so, pointers are 8 bytes for 64-bit.